# Bootstrap chosen add new item if no exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I am trying add new item if not exist. This code working but i dont know how add item directly on list of selected.

```
Chosen.prototype.no_results = function(terms) {
  var no_results_html;
  no_results_html = $('<li class="no-results">' + this.results_none_found + '"<span></span>" kao' +
    ' <button class="add" id="interni" class="submit"> Interni tip </button> ' +
    ' <button class="add" id="eksterni" class="submit"> Eksterni tip</button> ' +
    '</li> ');
  no_results_html.find("span").first().html(terms);
  no_results_html.find(".add").click(function() {

    var terms1 = terms + ' (' + this.id + ')';

    $('.chosen-select').chosen().append('<option>' + terms1 + '</option>');
    $('.chosen-select').chosen().trigger('chosen:updated');

  });
  return this.search_results.html(no_results_html);
};
```

resolved: Add selected atribute on option tag.

```
 $('.chosen-select').chosen().append('<option selected>' + terms1 + '</option>');
```

Comment: I am find this line but not working this.result_highlight = this.search_results.find('li.active-result').last();
                    return this.result_select(evt);

Comment: resolved:  add selected to option $('.chosen-select').chosen().append('<option selected>' + terms1 + '</option>');

Comment: If resolved add it as answer and accept after 18 hours . @BCM.